# Looping through all objects/sprites in a scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Is it possible to loop through all the objects contained in a scene when the override function "didMoveToView" is called? In context, I'm trying to check all the objects to see if one of them has the name "planet1" then make it orbit around a given point.

Comment: Loop through sibling views?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you need to loop through all the nodes just use

```
enumerateChildNodesWithName("//*", usingBlock: 
    { (node, stop) -> Void in  
        if node.name=="planet1" {
            //make it orbit
        }
    })
```

in the name string `//` means search the entire node tree, not just this node's children.
`*` is wildcard and matches any name, you can use `"xxx*"` to match any name starting with xxx and the same for `"*xxx"` to match any name ending in xxx

EDIT: you can just do:

```
planet1=self.childNodeWithName("//planet1")!
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through all of the parent view's subviews.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    super.didMoveToView(view)
    for sibling in view.subviews {
        // check sibling view
    }
}
```

Note that at least one of the objects in the loop will be equal to `self`.  Also note that they'll all have a type of `AnyObject`.  So you'll have to downcast.  If your view named "planet1" is a particular class though:

```
for sibling in view.subviews {
    if let planet = sibling as? PlanetSprite {
        if planet.name == "planet1" {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

This might be about what you're looking for.